# findOneAndUpdate Mongoose with Array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Im using Node.JS as backend and Angular4 as FrontEnd.

I want to make changes from angular in some row into an array with findOneAndUpdate

this is my model

```
        subLot: [{
          room: String,
          beforePicture: String,
          afterPicture: String,
          Realisations: [{
                realisationName : String,
                specialtyName : String,
                pu: Number,
                unite: String,
                quantite: Number,
                startDate: Date, // Attribute to Update
                endDate: Date, // Attribute to Update

          }]
        }]
```

The changes will be in "startDate" "endDate" where :

> (let body = req.body.subLot)   subLot[x].room == body[x].room &&
>   subLot[x].Realisations[y].realisationName ==
>   body[x].Realisations[y].realisationName

Here is my function in Node.JS

```
var lot = Devis.
    findOneAndUpdate({ "project": req.params.projectId }, { "$set": { "subLot": req.body.subLot } }).
    exec(function (err, lot) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).json({ lot: lot, success: true });

        return;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is updating an array field. But what you want to do is update one item of array field, subLot is an Array, and you want to update one of the value in that array not entire array.

I guess what you can do is fetch devis based on project id and then find appropriate lot for updating. As done in following code.

```
Devis.
findOne({ "project": req.params.projectId }).
  exec(function (err, devis) {
     if (err) {
         res.status(500).send(err);
         return;
     }
     var lottoUpdate = devis.subLot.find(function(l){ //using Array.find
          return l._id === lot._id;
     });
     lottoUpdate = lot; // update reference of found lot object to the lot object posted from angular.
     devis.save(function(err){
       if (err) {
         res.status(500).send(err);
         return;
      }
      res.status(200).json({ lot: lot, success: true }); 
     }); 
     return;
 })
```

Also I would recommend you to use promises rather then going for callbacks.